# How to not match given prefix in RegEx without negative lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, regex-negation

### Goal

The goal is matching a string in JavaScript without certain delimiters, i.e. a string **between two characters** (the characters can be included in the match).
For example, this string should be fully matched: `$ test string $`. This can appear anywhere in a string. That would be trivial, however, we want to allow escaping the syntax, e.g. `The price is 5\$ to 10\$`.

Summarized:

- Match any string that is enclosed by two `$` signs.
- Do not match it if the dollar signs are escaped using `\$`.

#### Solution using negative lookbehind

A solution that achieves this goal perfectly is: **`(?<!\\)\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$`**.

#### Problem

This solution uses **negative lookbehind**, which is *not supported on Safari*. How can the same matches be achieved without using negative lookbehind (i.e. on Safari)?

---

A solution that *partially* works is `(?<!\\)\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$`. However, this will also match the character in front of the `$` sign if it is not a `\`.

Comment: Is this ultimately a JavaScript question, or if not, then what is the language being used here?

Comment: Why not use simple `/\$([^$]+)\$/`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I should have specified - JavaScript. That is also why it does not work on Safari.

Comment: @Akxe This will still match `$foo\$` but worse than that, it will match `\$bar$` (`$bar$` will be matched without the backslash). The goal is to match the string when the dollar sign is escaped using a backslash.

Comment: Ok... then why not `\\\$([^$]+)\\\$`? Then simply extract the group you want from there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might rule out what you don't want by matching it, and capture what you want to keep in group 1

```
\\\$.*?\$|\$.*?\\\$|(\$.*?\$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qlvNqt/1)

Comment: I like the approach a lot. Will have to see if this fits the use case (because multiple regular expressions compete on a single string in a sense and the "unwanted" matches might interfere with that), but it seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex and grab your inner text using capture group #1 as you are already doing in your current regex using lookbehind:

```sh
(?:^|[^\\])\$((?:\\.|[^$])*)\$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1ttqo/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|[^\\])`: Match start position or a non-backslash character in a non-capturing group
- `\$`: Match starting `$`
- `(`: Start capturing group

  - `(?:\\.|[^$])*`: Match any escaped character or a non-`$` character. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `)`: End capturing group
- `\$`: Match closing `$`

PS: This regex will give same matches as your current regex: `(?<!\\)\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$`

Comment: Thanks, however, this has the downside that the match will include the character before the `$`. This is the same I mentioned in the question. This might interfere with logic where the whole match will be replaced.

Comment: Yes right if we have an input like `$ one $$ two $` then 2nd one won't be matched with this one. but you lookbehind regex is also using a capture group for text between `$` and so would this one.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot: `This is the same I mentioned in the question`: Are you sure you provided that in question? Because I just see `(?<!\\)\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$` being mentioned twice which is lookbehind based and doesn't match a character before match.

Comment: If your intent is to replace then I suggest [this solution](https://regex101.com/r/x1ttqo/2)